# Jquery toggle displacement

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using the bootstrap framework to build a menu as can be seen below. When I click on one of the links it toggles a div from hide to show.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id='createfolder'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Create a folder</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id='addproject'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Project File</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id='viewfiles'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> View Files & Versions</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id='find'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search Files & Versions</a></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery toggle code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search").hide();
  $("#find").click(function(){
    $("#search").toggle();
  });
});

<div id="search">
  <p>Some content that gets toggled back and forth</p>
</div>
```

The problem is when switching from one menu to another I end up with an additive effect where one button will stay open while the other one is clicked as demonstrated by this [Code IO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXEjrW).

I've come up with a quickfix with the following: http://codepen.io/thisperson/pen/QbqjvZ

Is there a better way to fix this issue? I'm trying to get it so when one button is clicked the other hides it's content and vice versa all the way across the menu so that if any one button is clicked the visible content is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic in your Codepen example is a lot more complicated that it needs to be. All you need to do on the click of a button is `hide()` one div, and `show()` another:

```
$("#add,#all").hide();

$("#addanime").click(function() {
    $("#all").hide();
    $("#add").show();
});

$("#viewall").click(function() {
    $("#all").show();
    $("#add").hide();
});
```

[**Updated Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOWady)

Comment: Is there any way I could loop through all the divs at once and toggle them rather than hiding each one individually.